# Use default date when converting Unix timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I am converting a unix timestamp to a date thusly

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(CAST( my_column AS BIGINT  ) / 1000 )
```

Attribute named ***my_column*** is a **TEXT** datatype. The developers have designed the source data to allow NULLs and it is breaking my code.

Is there a way I can write a coalesce statement that will convert my Unix timestamp or output a default date for a NULL value? I tried the following

```
CASE WHEN my_column IS NULL THEN '2001-01-01 00:00:00' ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(CAST( my_column AS BIGINT  ) / 1000 ) END
```

but I get an error

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
```

Any suggestion welcome.

Comment: why do you store numbers in a `text` column? and why don't you use a proper `timestamp` type?

Comment: Do your COALESCE() to a default value inside your cast: `TO_TIMESTAMP(CAST( COALESCE(my_column, 'yourdefaultnumericalvalue') AS BIGINT  ) / 1000 )`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name not my choice - developers decided that way.

Comment: @JNevill I tried your suggestion. I defaulted my numerical value to January 1st 2001 i.e. `978310861000` - Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that an empty string (`''`) can't be cast to a number.

You need to check for empty strings as well, something like:

```
CASE 
   WHEN nullif(trim(my_column),'') IS NULL THEN '2001-01-01 00:00:00' 
   ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(CAST( my_column AS BIGINT  ) / 1000 ) 
END
```

This will properly handle all null, empty strings or strings with only spaces. This can still fail if something that can't be cast to a number is stored in that column (e.g. `'foobar'`)

---

But you should really try to change that to at least a `bigint` column. A `timestamp` would be much better though